# ¿Cuantas opciones tengo para ocultar la consola para evitar ser vista en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: c++

Me gustaría saber cuantas opciones tengo para ocultar la consola cuando ejecuto mi aplicación, ya que no es interactiva y no me interesa que sea vista por el usuario, el usuario sabe que se esta ejecutando la aplicación ya que se va a mostrar un *MessageBox();* cuando la aplicación sea ejecutada. Ya probé diferentes códigos;

```
FreeConsole();
```

Despues:

```
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), 0);
```

Despues:

```
HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
```

Pero me llama la atención que se muestra la consola por menos de un segundo, cosa que me molesta (Con los 3 códigos me pasa lo mismo), ¿Es solamente cuando estoy depurando? ¿Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 me ofrece alguna opción para esta característica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya depende de la velocidad de la computadora al ejecutar la aplicación, si realmente te molesta que se vea ciertos segundos antes de ocultarse podrías:

1. Puedes crear un acceso directo del programa y en propiedades marcar que empiece la aplicación como minimizada.
2. Optar por desarrollar un Servicio de Windows que haga exactamente lo mismo, sin embargo, aquí no podras mostrar un MessageBox() [Servicio básico de Windows en C++](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppWindowsService-cacf4948)

Comment: Muy interesante tu respuesta, la voy a votar positiva mente porque aprendí algo nuevo aunque estoy con la intriga de como se podría lograr lo que tengo en mente, de cualquier forma agradezco mucho tu aporte.